# Creating VSCode Debugger Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm in the process of trying to write a VSCode extension to support basic SNES application development.  I already have a basic grammar definition and build task, so I have syntax highlighting, and am able to build my project with Ctrl+Shift+B using the bass v14 assembler, but now I'm trying to figure out how to launch the project using launch.json.  I've already worked through the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-debuggers) and played around with the mock debugger project, but I can't seem to figure out how to adapt it for my extension.  To start, I'm using the bsnes-plus emulator as my debugger.  There isn't really any command-line or IPC interface that will actually allow me to implement a proper debug adapter, so all I really want to do is to run the program and pass it my output file to launch.  For the time being, I'm assuming that bsnes-plus.exe is located in my $PATH, but eventually I'll try and figure out the best practices for external executable dependencies for an extension.

So here are my current questions:

- Is the "program" field of launch.json my compiled application, or is it bsnes-plus.exe?
- If "program" is my application, where do I specify bsnes-plus.exe?  Or vice versa.
- Is there a way to specify my own project-level variables, e.g. $OUTPUT so that I don't have to hard-code the output filename into both the build task and the launch task?
- At one point, I was able to get the launch command to open bsnes-plus, but not load the game, and when I closed it, VSCode complained that the debugger terminated unexpectedly and immediately re-opened bsnes-plus.  How do I avoid this?  Do I need to write a debug adapter even though it's not going to actually **do** anything other than launch the application, just so I can tell VSCode that it exited cleanly?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?  I'm going nowhere reading the vscode docs on the debug adapter API.  I'm trying to do basically the same as you did, except for C64 VICE emulator.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the "program" field of launch.json my compiled application, or is it bsnes-plus.exe?

This is entirely up to the debug extension. It's just passed through to the debug adapter. It usually corresponds to the specific app/script being debugged though, not the runtime that's running it, so I would suggest it should be your compiled application.

> If "program" is my application, where do I specify bsnes-plus.exe? Or vice versa.

You can put it any other field. In Dart, we have a `dartPath` field that can be passed through to the debug adapter. It's usually populated silently by the `DebugConfigurationProvider.resolveDebugConfig` though (we detect the SDK by searching `PATH`) so the user never needs to add it.

> Is there a way to specify my own project-level variables, e.g. $OUTPUT so that I don't have to hard-code the output filename into both the build task and the launch task?

You can't make your own variables, but using `resolveDebugConfig` you can manipulate the launch config yourself before it's passed to the debug adapter, which probably allows you to do what you need here (eg. you could do a string replace on `program` - or you could even just add it if it's not set, allowing a launch.json-less launch too).

> Do I need to write a debug adapter even though it's not going to actually do anything other than launch the application, just so I can tell VSCode that it exited cleanly?

I'm not sure what happened here without more details, but having a debug adapter probably makes the most sense - for example if you want to make the Stop/Restart buttons work on the toolbar, you'd probably want a debug adapter that can terminate and/or restart the process.